# How to Pivot using Python (Columns not fixed/Columns Dynamic )

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

How should I pivot the below data frame?

Dataframe value as below:

```
VNOTIFY ITEM    VALUE
820001  00001   5089571
820001  00002   5089580
820102  00001   5089491
820102  00001   5089492
820102  00001   5000133
820103  00001   5000137
```

to

```
VNOTIFY ITEM   VALUE1  VALUE2 VALUE3
820001  00001  5089571
820001  00002  5089580
820102  00001  5089491 5089492 5000133
820103  00001  5000137
```

```
df.pivot_table(index=['VNOTIFY','ITEM'], columns=['VNOTIFY','ITEM'], values='VALUE',aggfunc='first')
```

Didn't work

```
VNOTIFY ITEM   VALUE1  VALUE2 VALUE3
820001  00001  5089571
820001  00002  5089580
820102  00001  5089491 5089492 5000133
820103  00001  5000137
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM', df.groupby(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM']).cumcount() + 1]).unstack()`

Comment: OR `df.set_index(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM', df.groupby(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM']).cumcount() + 1]).VALUE.unstack().add_prefix('VALUE')`

Comment: PiR's nice q&a, and you can find your answer for question 10

Comment: Answer below                                                           
                                                                                       
df.set_index(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM', df.groupby(['VNOTIFY', 'ITEM']).cumcount() + 1]).VALUE.unstack().add_prefix('VALUE')     

                                              
                                                                                                                  
import numpy as np


df.reset_index().fillna(np.nan).replace('', np.nan)